# Android junit done button press

Tags: java, android, junit, sendkeys

In android junit, i have written a test case to enter some text into the edit text and then i need to click done button from the keypad. I have used to send desired text.
**String keysequence="R A N D O M SPACE T E X T"** 
**sendKeys(keysequence)** 
 But when i say
 **sendKeys("ENTER")** 
its going to a new line in edit text and not pressing done. I even tried 
 **sendKeys(Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE);**
 which is not working as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add android:lines="@integer/one" or right click the Edit text and select singleline to true

```
 android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: But the application is such taht it takes multiple lines and displays multiple lines of data.I need a way to click keypad done.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending DONE action directly:

```
public static void pressEnter(Instrumentation instrumentation, final EditText editText)
{
    instrumentation.runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            editText.onEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
        }
    });
    instrumentation.waitForIdleSync();
}
```

This helped me